# Matplotlib streamplot arrows pointing the wrong way

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I am generating a groundwater elevation contour and a streamplot in matplotlib

The contour indicates that the elevation is decreasing in many areas but the groundwater flow (streamplot) is pointed uphill. I have circled the arrows that seem to be pointed the wrong direction.

The arrows toward the bottom of the map appear to be pointed the correct direction. Does anyone know why this might be?

[image]

And here is most of the code which generates this plot:

```
#create empty arrays to fill up!
x_values = []
y_values = []
z_values = []

#iterate over wells and fill the arrays with well data
for well in well_arr:
    x_values.append(well['xpos'])
    y_values.append(well['ypos'])
    z_values.append(well['value'])

#initialize numpy array as required for interpolation functions
x = np.array(x_values, dtype=np.float)
y = np.array(y_values, dtype=np.float)
z = np.array(z_values, dtype=np.float)

#create a list of x, y coordinate tuples
points = zip(x, y)

#create a grid on which to interpolate data
xi, yi = np.linspace(0, image['width'], image['width']),
         np.linspace(0, image['height'], image['height'])
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

#interpolate the data with the matlab griddata function
zi = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi, interp='nn')

#create a matplotlib figure and adjust the width and heights
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(image['width']/72, image['height']/72))

#create a single subplot, just takes over the whole figure if only one is specified
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, frameon=False, xticks=[], yticks=[])

#create the contours
kwargs = {}
if groundwater_contours:
    kwargs['colors'] = 'b'

CS = plt.contour(xi, yi, zi, linewidths=linewidth, **kwargs)

#add a streamplot
dx, dy = np.gradient(zi)
plt.streamplot(xi, yi, dx, dy, color='c', density=1, arrowsize=3)
```

Comment: Can you show the code that generates the plot. Especially the part for contour lines and the arrows.

Comment: I have added the source code as requested. Interested to hear your thoughts.

Comment: how fine is the data?  You might be getting strange aliasing effects.

Comment: @tcaswell The data looks like this http://cl.ly/image/1S0y2z2p3j0X

Comment: That seems really sparse

Comment: @tcaswell Is there a way I could test or possibly inject some data the fix?

Comment: do you _have_ more data?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31126/discussion-between-nickwoodhams-and-tcaswell)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Summary

I'm guessing, but your problem is probably because you have an inherent transpose going on.  2D numpy arrays are indexed as row, column.  "x, y" indexing is column, row.  In this context, `numpy.gradient` is basically going to return dy, dx and not dx, dy.

Try changing the line:

```
dx, dy = np.gradient(zi)
```

to:

```
dy, dx = np.gradient(zi)
```

Also, if your depths are defined as positive-up, it should be:

```
dy, dx = np.gradient(-zi)
```

However, I'm assuming you have positive-down depth conventions, so I'll leave that part of of the examples below.  (So higher values are assumed to be deeper/lower in the example data below, and water will flow towards the high values.)

### Reproducing the problem

For example, if we modify the code you gave to use random data and fill in a few variables that are coming from outside the scope of your code sample (so that it's a stand-alone example):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata

# Generate some reproducible but random data
np.random.seed(1981)
width, height = 200, 300
x, y, z = np.random.random((3,10))
x *= width
y *= height

#create a list of x, y coordinate tuples
points = zip(x, y)

#create a grid on which to interpolate data
xi, yi = np.linspace(0, width, width), np.linspace(0, height, height)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

#interpolate the data with the matlab griddata function
zi = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi, interp='nn')

#create a matplotlib figure and adjust the width and heights
fig = plt.figure()

#create a single subplot, just takes over the whole figure if only one is specified
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, frameon=False, xticks=[], yticks=[])

#create the contours
CS = plt.contour(xi, yi, zi, linewidths=1, colors='b')

#add a streamplot
dx, dy = np.gradient(zi)
plt.streamplot(xi, yi, dx, dy, color='c', density=1, arrowsize=3)

plt.show()
```

The result will look like this:
[image]

Notice that there are lots of places where the flow lines are not perpendicular to the contours.  That's an even easier indicator than the incorrect direction of the arrows that something is going wrong.  (Though "perpendicular" assumes an aspect ratio of 1 for the plot, which isn't quite true for these plots unless you set it.)

### Fixing the problem

If we just change the line

```
dx, dy = np.gradient(zi)
```

to:

```
dy, dx = np.gradient(zi)
```

We'll get the correct result:

[image]

---

### Interpolation suggestions

On a side note, `griddata` is a poor choice in this case.

First, it's not a "smooth" interpolation method.  It uses delaunay triangulation, which makes "sharp" ridges at triangle boundaries.  This leads to anomalous gradients in those locations.

Second, it limits interpolation to the convex hull of your data points, which may or may not be a good choice.

A radial basis function (or any other smooth interpolant) is a much better choice for interpolation.

As an example, if we modify your code snippet to use an RBF:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import Rbf

# Generate data
np.random.seed(1981)
width, height = 200, 300
x, y, z = np.random.random((3,10))
x *= width
y *= height

#create a grid on which to interpolate data
xi, yi = np.mgrid[0:width:1j*width, 0:height:1j*height]

#interpolate the data with the matlab griddata function
interp = Rbf(x, y, z, function='linear')
zi = interp(xi, yi)

#create a matplotlib figure and adjust the width and heights
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(frameon=False, xticks=[], yticks=[]))

#create the contours and streamplot
CS = plt.contour(xi, yi, zi, linewidths=1, colors='b')
dy, dx = np.gradient(zi.T)
plt.streamplot(xi[:,0], yi[0,:], dx, dy, color='c', density=1, arrowsize=3)

plt.show()
```

[image]

(You'll notice the intersections are not quite perpendicular due to the non-equal aspect ratio of the plot. They're all 90 degrees if we set the aspect ratio of the plot to 1, however.)

As a side-by-side comparison of the two methods:

[image]

Comment: You are a total life saver. Swapping dx and dy fixed the arrows. Check out the before and after: http://cl.ly/image/1P3G3j1b0j1b

Comment: Question, why do you need `dy, dx = np.gradient(-zi)` when the depths are positive-up?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the arrow style with `arrowstyle='->'`. Try both of these and see if this works for you:

```
plt.streamplot(xi, yi, dx, dy, color='c', density=1, arrowsize=3, 
               arrowstyle='<-')

plt.streamplot(xi, yi, dx, dy, color='c', density=1, arrowsize=3, 
               arrowstyle='->')
```

Comment: I tried both of those, it looks like the arrows are still pointing in the wrong direction. http://cl.ly/image/2q3U3V0q0L2B

Comment: I got them to turn into different directions depending on `'<-'` or `'->'`.

Comment: I did too, but then the arrows at the bottom are pointed the wrong direction instead of the arrows at the top.