# Contour plot of xyz format

Tags: python, matrix, matplotlib, plot, contour

I am still struggling with this guys, I have tried the suggestion on this post already. I think my brain isn't working well so I really need a dumbed down answer:

So I have data in the format of a matrix i.e.:

```
[x1,y1,val]
[x1,y2,val]
[x1,y3,val]
[x1,y4,val]
[x1,y5,val]
..........
[x2,y1,val]
[x2,y2,val]
[x2,y3,val]
[x2,y4,val]
[x2,y5,val]
```

where val is some number. Basically I want to plot a contour using this and have tried using a number of examples as a starting point but am still unsure of how to proceed. I want something of this kind:
http://www.astro.ex.ac.uk/people/mbate/Animations/Stellar/pgplot_0259_outflow.png
where the x and y are the RA and DEC. Thanks!

Comment: I usually use matplotlib in python for my plotting of this nature. There's a post about it here that might be helpful for your work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529892/adding-water-flow-arrows-to-matplotlib-contour-plot

Comment: Do I need to interpolate my x's and y's or can I just use the step size directly from the data?

Comment: From the data should be fine. A little more searching and it seems like the "quiver" approach is what you want. See this matplotlib documentation: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/quiver_demo.html

Comment: You should post some code you tried, so we can better guide you to a result. The data you showed should be usable without interpolation. You just need to create the correct arrays (see e.g. numpy.meshgrid or contour docu).

Comment: right well I see what you mean. For x and y creating the mesh is trivial, I can just do:
xi, yi = np.mgrid[1:15:1, 1:15:1]

I am unsure about how to proceed with the z since this is essentially the actual data. So my question now is I know I can extract the values from the matrix to form a 1-d z list but how do I then convert it into a mesh of a similar form as for x and y? Cheers!

Comment: most of the examples that I have seen seem to generate their z values using the x and y since there is a function involved. However in my case I only have numbers. I am trying to use the x and y points as matrix positions and to form an array of z but again can't get it to be a 2d array as required by contour.